# does JNI introduce an extra thread for native code?

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk

I currently using android NDK to write some native code in C. I have learned that using JNI we can make two way calls from java to C and from C to java.

I am curious if using JNI introduces an extra thread implicitly or is it still one main() thread for the app ?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know about the Android VM, but the Sun virtual machine uses whatever thread called the native code to execute the native code.

Comment: @Bill thanks for the info. So if I make java -> c -> Java call, would it come back to java code on the same thread which initiated the call in case of sun jvm ?

Comment: Sounds feasible. I would test it first though. I standard Java, I would something like print `Thread.currentThread().getName()` call my native code have it call my Java code and then print the current thread name again.

Comment: Thanks for the advise :) I would do that to confirm ..

Comment: If it works, you should post your answer to help the next person who has this question.

Comment: @Bill Yes it has worked out its, on the same thread..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dalvik Java VM in Android calls the native code from the current Java-thread. It can be any thread - UI or any other. Your native code is free to spawn new threads at will.

Of course, the call java->native->java will return to the same thread it was invoked in.